# is there any thing similar to bp_get_member_id in buddypress?

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

Does anybody know how can i get the member id in a loop of buddy press:

```
  `<?php while ( bp_members() ) : bp_the_member(); ?>`
```

there is the bp_member_name, but i dont know how to get the id....
any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use:

```
  bp_get_member_user_id()
```

That should get you the member id.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

i found the answer in the budy press forum :

bp_member_user_id() to echo the ID

and bp_get_member_user_id() to get the ID